# Tkinter treeview selection of mutiple rows and retrieve the selected rows

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am using the sample Treeview widget for the user to select the multiple rows. I used the tree.selection method for this in the code.

However, I am unable to figure out a better approach to retrieve the selected rows in an appropriate way. For example, If the user selects the IDs with 1 and 2. Then I would like to use the Price ,Items information etc for the different task. If the user selects all the three rows then so on .... Below is the working sample, I tried to split it and saved it in the variables but it will not work if the user select one or two rows ?[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk

def Tree_Focus_Area():
    curItems = tree.selection()
    Var=",".join([str(tree.item(i)['values']) for i in curItems])
    a, b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l = str(Var).split(",")
    print("The selected items for the first ID:", a,b,c,d)
    print("The selected items for the second ID:", e,f,g,h)
    print("The selected items for the second ID:", i,j,k,l)

root = tk.Tk()
tree = tkinter.ttk.Treeview(root, height=4)

tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree['columns'] = ('ID', 'Items', 'Price', 'Priority')
tree.heading("#1", text='ID', anchor='w')
tree.column("#1", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#2", text='Items', anchor='w')
tree.column("#2", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#3", text='Price', anchor='w')
tree.column("#3", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#4", text='Priority', anchor='w')
tree.column("#4", stretch="no")
tree.pack()

tree.insert("", "end", values=["1", "Laptop", "$1000.50", "10"])
tree.insert("", "end", values=["2", "Desktop Equipment", "$800.50", "5"])
tree.insert("", "end", values=["3", "Office Supplies", "$467.50", "7"])

tree.bind("<Return>", lambda e: Tree_Focus_Area())

root.mainloop()
```

```
Updated code 

def Tree_Focus_Area(): #from @acw1668
    selections = tree.selection()
    rows = [tree.item(i, 'values') for i in selections]
    return tuple(rows)

root = tk.Tk()
tree = tkinter.ttk.Treeview(root, height=4)

tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree['columns'] = ('ID', 'Items', 'Price', 'Priority')
tree.heading("#1", text='ID', anchor='w')
tree.column("#1", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#2", text='Items', anchor='w')
tree.column("#2", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#3", text='Price', anchor='w')
tree.column("#3", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#4", text='Priority', anchor='w')
tree.column("#4", stretch="no")
tree.pack()

tree.insert("", "end", values=["1", "Laptop", "$1000.50", "10"])
tree.insert("", "end", values=["2", "Desktop Equipment", "$800.50", "5"])
tree.insert("", "end", values=["3", "Office Supplies", "$467.50", "7"])

tree.bind("<Return>", lambda e: Tree_Focus_Area())

****Trying to access the tuple outside the function here****
var = Tree_Focus_Area()
print(var) #Returning empty if I use this way?

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the `values` tuple of the selected rows and append them to a list:

```py
def Tree_Focus_Area():
    selections = tree.selection()
    rows = [tree.item(i, 'values') for i in selections]
    for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        print(f"The selected items for ID #{i}:", ', '.join(row))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm. Could you please explain me what is the purpose of 1 in the second for loop ?

One last question, how do I return and access outside the function ? When I try to return and call the function Tree_Focus_Area(). It says "TclError: invalid command name ".!treeview" ??

Comment: 1 in the second for loop is the starting value of `i`.  Which data you want to use outside the function?

Comment: I was curious, if I have to return the tuple in that function by using return rows. Can I retrieve the tuple values outside the function using the statement, var = Tree_focus_Area() ?

Comment: @data_weed For this case, yes.

Comment: I tried but it is returning empty. So, I tried returning it using the statement as return tuple(rows). And still, it is returning empty outside the function ? Thank you, much appreciate your time
'''
def Tree_Focus_Area():
    selections = tree.selection()
    rows = [tree.item(i, 'values') for i in selections]
    rows = tuple(rows)
    return rows

var = Tree_Focus_Area()
print("Tuple outside the function", var)
'''

Comment: Did you call the function *after* you have selected items in the treeview?

Comment: I have updated the code in the main post with the comments, what I am trying to do.

Comment: It is because you call the function just after creating the treeview, so no item is selected yet.

Comment: So, which is the appropriate way to call? If I try to call before creating the treeview, it says no tree defined as expected. So, I am little confused.

Comment: You need to call it when you require it.  That is what I can tell you, you need to think clearly about it yourself.